# history=model.fit_generator() Why is keras history empty?{}

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, tensorboard, tf.keras

I can't obtain history from `model.fit_generator()`

```
net_history=densenet_model.fit_generator(
  generator=train_loader,
  steps_per_epoch=len(train_dataset), 
  max_queue_size=500,
  workers=1,
  validation_data=val_loader,
  epochs=10, 
  validation_steps=len(val_dataset),
  verbose=0,
  callbacks=[checkpointer, tensorboard]
)
print(net_history.history)
print(net_history.history.keys())
```

result:

```
  {}
  dict_keys([])
```

But I can obtain history information from `model.fit()`

```
net_history2=densenet_model.fit(
  x_train,
  y_train,
  validation_split=0.3,
  epochs=4,
  verbose=0,
  batch_size=4,
  callbacks=[checkpointer, tensorboard]
)
print(net_history2.history)
```

result:

```
{'val_loss': [1.0166720993050904, 0.8762002832421633, 0.9079110455290179, 0.8696109705439238], 
'val_categorical_crossentropy': [0.8133353590965271, 0.677170991897583, 0.7131518721580505, 
0.6792631149291992], 'val_categorical_accuracy': [0.5887850522994995, 0.6355140209197998, 
0.5794392228126526, 0.6074766516685486], 'loss': [0.8654926233446067, 0.8416075144219495, 
0.8553338176325748, 0.8491003025881192], 'categorical_crossentropy': [0.6599225, 0.6403823, 
0.6583931, 0.6564969], 'categorical_accuracy': [0.6396761, 0.659919, 0.5991903, 0.562753]}
```

Why does this happen?

How can I get the loss and accuracy information from model.fit_generator？

ps: I failed to visualize iterative process through log event because each time I try to open it in tensorboard, the browser gets stuck in   'namespace hierarchy finding similar subgraphs' and then crashes... QAQ

Answer (score 0):

You can stick with model.fit becuase it supports generators.

For TensorBoard you may want to wait a little bit longer (I thought that tensorboard stucked in  'namespace hierarchy finding similar subgraphs' but it was running and it took some time).

---

Note: for training and validation steps you should get the length of the generators which is equal to trainORval_dataset_size / batch size, not the length of the dataset. You don't want the same images to be repeated in the same epoch.

```
steps_per_epoch=len(train_loader)
validation_steps=len(val_loader)
```

Answer (score 0):

As for why exactly this is happening I can only speculate that it is because model.fit_generator is deprecated, in TensorFlow 2.2 and higher you can just use model.fit because this now supports generators.

Source:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit_generator